# While loop is not working?

Tags: java, multithreading

It may seem dumb, but I'm stuck here.
**My code:**

```
String status = "INPROCESS"    
logger.info("Job status: 1. "+prevStatus);
    logger.info("Job status: 2. "+status);
    while (!status.equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR") && !status.equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETE")) {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        map = ConfigUtils.getJobStatus(jobDetailsBean, processTaskBean);
        status = map.get("status");
        logger.info("Job status: 3. "+status);
    }
```

**what prints on my screen is:**

```
Job status: 1. IN_PROCESS
Job status: 2. IN_PROCESS
```

**My Question:**
Why is it not going inside the loop when the value is neither ERROR nor COMPLETE?

This code is running on a thread started by another thread using executor framework.
Currently status is INPROCESS.

```
ConfigUtils.getJobStatus(jobDetailsBean, processTaskBean);
```

this runs and updates the status of the job. Now when thread runs, it prints the logs and then skips the while loop completely, resulting in non updation of status.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so that we can try to reproduce the problem? (In particular, what are those constants?)

Answer (score -1):

You're asking for "either" situation, in that case put || (OR) instead of && (AND).

In your case it will check for both condition.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's not working - because both conditions are true at the moment. The status isn't ERROR *and* the status isn't COMPLETE... assuming those constants have sensible values. If the OP changed it to `||` then the loop could *never* complete, unless `ERROR` and `COMPLETE` have the same value, as the status would either be "not equal to error" or "not equal to complete".